# Get a table as a column in SQL

Tags: sql

Lets say we have 2 tables: books and chapters. Each book has many chapters.

books

id,title

chapters

id,title,book_id

How can I can get all the book titles and also an array of objects with all the chapters belonging to that book? For example:

```
{
id:1,
title: Book 1
chapters:[
  {
   id:1,
   title: Chapter 1,
   book_id: 1,
   },
  {
   id:2,
   title: Chapter 2,
   book_id: 1,
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: You should share your code to show your effort and after we can correct your mistake.

Comment: SQL generally does not output JSON. If you want to achieve that, you need first to do the query with the join, and then iterate over your result to generate the JSON objet you want. The process to generate the JSON depends on the tool you are using to extract the data.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the SQL query, you can just go for a simple join between the two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM books b INNER JOIN chapters c
ON b.id=c.book_id
```

then, if you need to convert the result in an object you should specify which language, framework, orm, etc... you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is just to build json with given structure, try the following code:

```
SELECT b.id as id, b.title as title, c.js as Chapters 
FROM books b 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT id, title, book_id 
    FROM chapters c 
    WHERE b.id = c.book_id
    FOR JSON PATH
)c(js)
FOR JSON PATH
```